# Is it possible to customize the style of javafx native package installer?

Tags: javafx, inno-setup, self-contained

I have a javafx application which I package it with javafx-maven-plugin (windows installer).
I could also package it with ANT script.

My question is, I could change the Icon of the installer. But is it possible to change the install wizard style? like button colors, caption, add a logo, background image, etc?

Comment: I do not think that there is one answer to all this questions. Ask them separately.

Comment: As you are using inno setup behind the scenes to generate the installer, I advise you study the [inno setup documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to understand the customization possibilities of that tool and how they may be leveraged in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are several 3rd party components which allows to change the design of Inno Setup installer.

The most well known and officially recommended (http://jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php) by Inno Setup are:

1) **Graphical Installer** (http://www.graphical-installer.com) - extension that allows to customize almost every aspect of installer (background, buttons, icons, fonts, colors, ...). Commercial plug-in (I was personally involved in development):

[image: Graphical Installer]

2) **VCL Styles for Inno Setup** (https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup) - free and Open Source plugin (dll) that allows you to add skins to the Inno Setup installers.

[image: VCL Styles]

3) **ISSkin** (http://isskin.codejock.com/) - free version of Codejock’s Skin Framework that allows add customized skins to installer.

[image: ISSKin]

Comment: This is not a generic Inno Setup question. I believe the primary problem of the OP is that he is using JavaFX.

Comment: Yes, I am using Inno Setup just because Oracle document recommend it. All I need is a customizable JavaFx package installer and customize its style.